# (Python) Vending Machine program returning wrong amount of money inserted?

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, while-loop

I just recently started teaching myself Python (3.5.1) and have written a few basic programs. I am trying to write a program that allows a user to purchase 3 products maximum. However, I am having trouble with getting the correct value for the total amount of money inserted, which I am guessing is because it keeps re-initializing itself. Any help is appreciated. Also, is my code too complicated and if so, how can I simplify it?
**Updated Code:**

```
def main():
   displayPrices()
   purchaseItems()

def displayPrices():
   print("Item ID:\tCost: ")
   print("1\t\t$1.25")
   print("2\t\t$0.75")
   print("3\t\t$0.90")
   print("4\t\t$0.75")
   print("5\t\t$1.50")
   print("6\t\t$0.75")

def purchaseItems():
   choice=""
   numItems=0
   totalCost=0
   totalReturned=0
   item=0
   change=0
   x=0
   money=float(input("Insert the amount of money you would like to input: $"))
   totalInserted=money
   while x < 3:
         item=int(input("\nWhich item would you like to purchase?\nIf you would like to quit, enter '0': "))
         if item == 1:
            cost = 1.25
         elif item == 2:
            cost = .75
         elif item == 3:
            cost = .90
         elif item == 4:
            cost = .75
         elif item == 5:
            cost = 1.50
         elif item == 6:
            cost = .75
         elif item == 0:
            print("Thank you for using our Vending Machine. Goodbye!")
            break
         else:
            print("Error. Please enter a valid Item ID [1-6]")
         if cost <= money:
               change = money - cost
               numItems+=1
               money=change
               totalCost=totalCost+cost
               totalReturned=change
               print("Thank you for purchasing Item " + str(item) + ". Your change is $" + str(round(change,2)) + ".\n")
               x+=1
         else:
            moneyNeeded = cost - money
            print("Please enter an additional $" + str(moneyNeeded) + " to purchase your item.")
            newMoney=float(input("Insert the amount of money you would like to input: $"))
            totalInserted=money=money+newMoney
#  End of Loop

   print("Numbers of Items Purchased:", numItems)
   print("Total cost of all Items Purchased:", totalCost)
   print("Total amount of money inserted:", round(totalInserted,2))
   print("Total amount of change returned:", round(totalReturned,2))

main()
```

Take a look at the following output:
Item ID:    Cost:
 
1       $1.25
2       $0.75
3       $0.90
4       $0.75
5       $1.50
6       $0.75
Insert the amount of money you would like to input: $0

Which item would you like to purchase?
If you would like to quit, enter '0': 1
Please enter an additional $1.25 to purchase your item.
Insert the amount of money you would like to input: $1.00

Which item would you like to purchase?
If you would like to quit, enter '0': 2
Thank you for purchasing Item 2. Your change is $0.25.

Which item would you like to purchase?
If you would like to quit, enter '0': 1
Please enter an additional $1.0 to purchase your item.
Insert the amount of money you would like to input: $1.0

Which item would you like to purchase?
If you would like to quit, enter '0': 1
Thank you for purchasing Item 1. Your change is $0.0.

Which item would you like to purchase?
If you would like to quit, enter '0': 0
Thank you for using our Vending Machine. Goodbye!
Numbers of Items Purchased: 2
Total cost of all Items Purchased: 2.0
Total amount of money inserted: **1.25** --- This is incorrect
Total amount of change returned: 0.0

Comment: Note that the only difference between each branch in that `if` structure is the cost of the item. You can move everything else out of it and make your program half of its current size.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 didn't even notice as I was copying+pasting, fixed that, however I still don't know what to do about the total inserted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was surprised this line even ran without error, but apparently it's a valid construct:

```
totalInserted=money=money+newMoney
```

In that line `totalInserted` is getting assigned the value of `money`. However, `money` currently available is not the same as `totalInserted`. What you really want is this:

```
money += newMoney
totalInserted += newMoney
```

As for if your code is too complicated, one suggestion to make it simpler would be to store the item/price relationship in a dictionary:

```
prices = {1:1.25, 2:.75, ...}
```

Then later you can just do this:

```
cost = prices[item]
```

You'd still need to first check if `item` was `0` or an invalid input. You also have a variable, `choice` that is never used.

Comment: How would I check if item was 0 or invalid (not in the range of 1-6)?

Comment: Manually like you were, but taking advantage of dictionary constructs. If item == 0: ... elif item not in prices: ...

Comment: Im not very comfortable with dictionaries yet as this is the first time I've used one, however I decided to use if item>0 and item<7 elif item==0 else _error message_ which worked

Comment: Nothing wrong with doing it the way that makes the most sense for you, especially when you're learning. In the long run, the strictly dictionary approach is nice because if you want to, say, add or delete an item, you only have to change your code in one place, vs. three right now (in the dictionary, in displayPrices, and in the bound of your if statement). However, you can just cross that bridge when you come to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here may be one solution.

```
def main():
   displayPrices()
   purchaseItems()


def displayPrices():
   print("Item ID:\tCost: ")
   print("1\t\t$1.25")
   print("2\t\t$0.75")
   print("3\t\t$0.90")
   print("4\t\t$0.75")
   print("5\t\t$1.50")
   print("6\t\t$0.75")


def purchaseItems():
    money = float(input("How much money would you like to insert?"))
    moneyInserted = money
    items_sold = 0
    items = [1.25, .75, .9, .75, 1.5, .75]
    moneySpent = 0
    total_cost = 0
    x = 1
    while x != 0 and money > 0 and items_sold < 3:
        print("You have $" + str(money) + " left.")
        x = int(input("What item would you like to buy?"))
        if x == 0:
            pass
        elif x < 1 or x > 6:
            print("Please return a valid item number.")
        elif money >= items[x-1]:
            print("Thank you for buying item "+str(x)+".")
            money -= items[x-1]
            moneySpent += items[x-1]
            total_cost += items[x-1]
            items_sold += 1

        else:
            pass
    print("Number of items sold: " + str(items_sold))
    print("Money Inserted: " + str(moneyInserted))
    print("Amount of money spent: " + str(total_cost))
    print("Change amount: " + str(money))


main()
```